# Laravel question: How can I change the email field to username?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently using the default Authentication of Laravel (php artisan make:auth)

But since it's very crucial for us to change the email-field to a username-field, I will need some help on that. I already tried to give it a shot, but I couldn't figure it out.

Help would be nice.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have seen a post where someone suggested to add a function to the login-controller:     public function username()
    {
        return ‘username’;
    }, but then I get: "use of undefined constant."

Comment: Maybe you can try to just remove the e-mailaddress? 
From the login controller, from the validator and from the form?

Or just change its name

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/

Comment: I have fixed the issue by myself now, thanks anyways, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in the [authentication quickstart](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart) from the Laravel's Documentation at the "Username Customization" paragraph, you can easily customize the data that the user use to authenticate :

> By default, Laravel uses the email field for
>   authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a
>   username method on your LoginController :

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Comment: this link belongs to laravel 5.7 .. as a notice

Answer (score 0):

Beside @JeuneApprenti answer you also needs to make changes to RegisterController.php because email is declared required. So you may need to change it and also insert and make username as required.
So in validator method of RegisterController

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
```

and also the method create

```
return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
```

Also you need to make changes to AuthenticatesUsers.php because LoginController uses it against validation.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

First delete the users table. and then execute migration again.

```
DROP TABLE users;
```

Also delete the entry that user table migration is done.

```
DELETE FROM migrations where migration = '2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table';
```

Do make changes to database migrations file for users. In 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php file in database/migrations folder. Change the method up as

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->enum('authority', ['admin','oper','guest']);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now execute the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Plus now that you had declared username in database we also need to make changes in the Auth forms to insert the username filed in the html

First make changes to resources/views/auth/register.blade.php form. Add the following code after email. (In case you didn't need email then replace the following code with email div block.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username">

                            @error('username')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

You may need to rerun npm to recreate app.js

npm run dev

Also make changes to login.blade.php form in /resources/views/auth folder.

Replace the following

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

with

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('User Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                            @error('username')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Lastly make changes to app/User.php model.

Change fillable array to

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
];
```