# 302 On logout and login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, csrf, middleware

I have a problem with the laravel sessions or with crsf tokens of laravel, I dont know.

My laravel installation (v7.x) has a typical login (generated with 1php artisan make:auth1), and my problem is when I need close my session (post request to `/logout` route), I see in my navigator network a `302 code` request, but in my form I have my `csrf token` and I can see it in the post request.

Sometimes I can "execute" the logout, laravel redirect me to `/login` route, but in my navigator i put manually the `/home` route (I need to be athenticated to enter here) and I see that my session is still open :|

Any ideas?

My web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware(['auth', 'web'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'AppController@index')
        ->name('home');

    // Orders
    Route::get('/order/detail/{id}', 'AppController@show_order_detail')
        ->name('show_order_detail');
    Route::get('/order/list', 'AppController@show_order_list')
        ->name('show_order_list');
    Route::post('/order/update/status', 'AppController@update_order_status')
        ->name('update_order_status');
    Route::post('/order/search_order', 'AppController@search_order')
        ->name('search_order');
    Route::post('/order/filter_orders_by_status', 'AppController@filter_orders_by_status')
        ->name('filter_orders_by_status');

    // Refund
    Route::get('/order/refund/{id}', 'AppController@show_refund')
        ->name('show_refund');
    Route::post('/order/send_refund', 'AppController@send_refund')
        ->name('send_refund');

    // Users
    Route::get("/administration/users", "AdministrationController@users_list")
        ->name("users_list");
    Route::get("/administration/users/add", "AdministrationController@show_form_add_user")
        ->name("add_user");
    Route::post("/administration/users/add/send", "AdministrationController@add_user_send")
        ->name("add_user_send");

    Route::get("/administration/users/detail/{userId}", "AdministrationController@user_detail")
        ->name("user_detail");
    Route::post("/administration/users/setpassword", "AdministrationController@user_setpassword")
        ->name("user_setpassword");

    // Audit Log
    Route::get("/administration/audit", "AdministrationController@show_audit")
        ->name("show_audit");
});
```

My logout form (its a link with a javascript event)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
       onclick="event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        {{ __('Logout') }}
    </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 302 is not an error status code

Comment: Have you altered the `logout` function in the `LoginController` at all? Your form and `routes` look OK.

Comment: I changed the email field (for principal authentication) for a new field in users table named "username", and in my LoginController i adderd this code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591165/laravel-question-how-can-i-change-the-email-field-to-username/52591309